# How can I use "cp --sparse=always" in Mac?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, cp, sparse-file

I just follow [this page](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/compute-iaas/creating_a_custom_ol_machine_image/creating_a_custom_ol_machine_image.html#section10) to build custom oracle linux machine image.

I want to use cp `cp --sparse=always` like *Converting the VM Disk to a Machine Image* of that page in my Mac. But, my Mac cannot recognize this option. How can I follow this step in my Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `cp` in linux is same with `gcp`(GNU cp) in Mac.
I can run `gcp --sparse=always` in my Mac. 
If you cannot run `gcp` in your mac, Please refer [this page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities).